# SASS breaks my selector

Tags: compilation, compression, sass

I'm having trouble with SASS.  Locally I have this selector:

```
#featured-categories{
        ul{           
            li{
                width: 33.33%;
            }
         }
}
```

which works as expected.  Deployed (and compressed) however this is compiling to:

```
#featured-categoriesulli{width: 33.33%;}
```

which of course is an invalid selector.  The more straight more forward formulation:

```
#featured-categories ul li{
    width: 33.33%;
}
```

behaves in the same way - i.e. compiles to something munged and broken.

The only way I can get this to compile is to add redundant rules between the elements of the selector:

```
#featured-categories{
        margin: 0;
        ul{
            margin: 0;
            li{
                width: 33.33%;
            }
         }
}
```

This works, but is obviously not ideal.

Can anyone help?  I'm in a ruby 1.9.3 project running sass 3.2.9.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sass doesn't compile like that, do you have another compressor going over the generated CSS afterwards?

Answer (score -1):

The SCSS that you've provided should work fine.  Check it out with [SassMeister](http://sassmeister.com/) or http://jsfiddle.net/Kjanu/.  It will compile to this:

```
#featured-categories ul li { width: 33.33%; }
```

So you've got something else going wrong in your setup.